# How to return actual value (not lowercase) when performing search with terms aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am working on an ElasticSearch (6.2) project where the `index` has many `keyword` fields and they are normalized with `lowercase` filter for performing case-insensitive searches. The search working great and returning actual values (not lowercase) of the normalized fields. However, the aggregations not returning the actual value (returning lowercase) of the fields.

The following example has been taken from ElasticSearch doc.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/normalizer.html

Creating index:

```
PUT index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "my_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [],
          "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "foo": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Inserting a doc:

```
PUT index/_doc/1
{
  "foo": "Bar"
}

PUT index/_doc/2
{
  "foo": "Baz"
}
```

Search with aggregation:

```
GET index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "foo_terms": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "foo"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "took": 43,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 0.0,
    "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 0.47000363,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.47000363,
        "_source": {
          "foo": "Bar"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.47000363,
        "_source": {
          "foo": "Baz"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "foo_terms": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "bar",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "baz",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If you check the aggregation, you will see that lowercase value has been returned. e.g. `"key": "bar"`.

Is there any way to change the aggregation to return actual value?

e.g. `"key": "Bar"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to do case-insensitive search yet return exact values in your aggregations you don't need any normalizer. You can simply have a `text` field (which lowercases the tokens and allows case-insensitive search by default) with a `keyword` sub-field. You'd use the former for search and the latter for aggregations. It goes like this:

```
PUT index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "foo": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After indexing your two documents, your can issue a `terms` aggregation on `foo.keyword`:

```
GET index/_search
{
  "size": 2,
  "aggs": {
    "foo_terms": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "foo.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the result would look like this:

```
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "foo": "Baz"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "foo": "Bar"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "foo_terms": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "Bar",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "Baz",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does it allow exact match search like keyword?

Comment: Yes, by searching on `foo.keyword` you can search exact values and when searching on `foo` you can search case insensitively.

Comment: this fits my use-case very well, however, in addition to the above 2 conditions (case insensitive & aggregation use). it also needs wildcard support while still retaining original value after aggregation.
how should the mapping be formulated?

Comment: @MarcusLim please create a new question (maybe referencing this one) and explain your additional use case.